# IOS - Memory Management - Recursive call to NSURLConnection causes Memory Usage to Increase

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks

I have a function that gets called recursively to get new data from the database depending on the latest date. My problem is that this recursive call made causes memory usage to increase. I have commented out code to see what line is cause 300kb to be Allocated every time, so whats happening is that every time the NSURLConnection is hit i get memory usage to be increased by 300kb every 10 seconds.

This is the method that gets called recursively:

```
-(NSString*)setupPhpCall:(NSString*)requestString :(NSString*)sciptPage{
@autoreleasepool {

    //NSURLCache *sharedCache = [[NSURLCache alloc] initWithMemoryCapacity:0 diskCapacity:0 diskPath:0];
    //[NSURLCache setSharedURLCache:sharedCache];


    NSHTTPURLResponse *urlresponse = nil;
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSString *response = @"";
    NSData *myRequestData = nil;
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = nil;
    NSData *returnData = nil;

    myRequestData = [NSData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

     //Create your request string with parameter name as defined in PHP file
    request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://www.hugt.co.uk/%@", sciptPage]]];
    // set Request Type
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    // Set content-type
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];
    // Set Request Body
    [request setHTTPBody: myRequestData];
    // Now send a request and get Response
    //NSHTTPURLResponse* urlResponse = nil;
    //NSError *error = nil;

    //if(tmpArray.count == 0){
        returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlresponse error: &error]; //THIS LINE CAUSES THE MEMORY USAGE TO INCREASE
        response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //}
    // Log Response
    urlresponse = nil;
    error = nil;
    myRequestData = nil;
    request = nil;
    returnData = nil;

     //NSLog(@"%@",response);/****/
    //[sharedCache removeAllCachedResponses];
    if(response != nil){

        return response;
    }

}
return nil;
}
```

This is what i do with the response:

```
-(void)recurseForumActivity{
@autoreleasepool {
    __block __weak dispatch_queue_t concurrentQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);

    dispatch_async(concurrentQueue, ^{


         myRequestStringForum = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"lastDate=%@&threadTitle=%@&threadCountry=%@&threadCategory=%@&threadSubCategory=%@&getData=0",lastDateForumActivity,searchThreadTitle, searchThreadCountry, searchThreadCategory, searchThreadSubCategory];
         responseForum = [self setupPhpCall:myRequestStringForum :@"xxx.php"];

            [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0f];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            if(responseForum.length > 0 && ![responseForum isEqualToString:@"[]"]){

                labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ new threads...", responseForum];







                if(imageviewForumAlert == NULL){
                    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"alert.png"];

                    imageviewForumAlert = [UIImageView new];
                    [viewNav1 addSubview:imageviewForumAlert];
                    imageviewForumAlert.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
                    imageviewForumAlert.image = image;

                    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = @{@"imageviewForumAlert":imageviewForumAlert};
                    NSArray *constraint_H = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-19-[imageviewForumAlert(12)]-19-|"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];

                    NSArray *constraint_V = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-19-[imageviewForumAlert(12)]-19-|"
                                                                                    options:0
                                                                                    metrics:nil
                                                                                      views:viewsDictionary];



                    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_H];
                    [self.view addConstraints:constraint_V];



                }else{
                    imageviewForumAlert.hidden = NO;

                }
                /**NSDictionary *dic = [response JSONValue];
                if((NSNull*)dic != [NSNull null]){

                    labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d new threads...", dic.count];

                }**/

            }else{

                imageviewForumAlert.hidden = YES;



                labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d new threads...", 0];
            }
            /**else{
                labelNewForumThreads.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d new threads...", 0];
            }**/
            myRequestStringForum = @"";
            responseForum = @"";
            concurrentQueue = nil;

            [self recurseForumActivity];
        });

    });
}

}
```

Comment: How big is the `response` string that you're returning? What are you doing with that string?

Comment: @Rob, i have edited.

Comment: In this fucntion really its coming back with a null or a 1 but in other function the data is json

Comment: @Rob, any clues. This has been bugging me for 3 days. I cant seem to find a solution

Comment: when i comment out these two lines returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&urlresponse error: &error]; //THIS LINE CAUSES THE MEMORY USAGE TO INCREASE
        response = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[returnData bytes] length:[returnData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    //} memory usage is stable

Comment: @Rob i am setting the NSSTring to @"" and dictionary to nil when i have finished with them, but still get memory use to increase

Comment: OK, time for you to pull out Instruments and diagnose what's really going on. See WWDC video 2013 [Fixing Memory Issues](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/?id=410) or WWDC 2012 video [iOS App Performance: Memory](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=242).

Comment: ok ill have a look thanks @Rob

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82015/discussion-between-rob-and-redoc01).